# How to hide TextFieldCursorHandle in Jetpack compose for TextField/BasicTextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

The solution I have so far is to use a `Transparent` Color for the cursor.
I am looking for a better way to hide it if there is any.

```
cursorBrush = SolidColor(Transparent)
```

TextField should be focused, the keyboard should be open and the user should be able to type input.

[image: Screenshot]

The problem with this is I can still see the `TextFieldCursorHandle` after entering text.

[image]

Comment: Yes. You can apply `cursorBrush  = SolidColor(Color.Transparent)` to your `BasicTextField`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, It doesn't hide `TextFieldCursorHandle`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- In the `BasicTextField` you can hide the cursor using **`cursorBrush = SolidColor(Unspecified)`**.
- In the `TextField`you can use the attribute **`colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(cursorColor = Color.Unspecified)`**

The `TextFieldCursorHandle` and the selected text use the color provided by `LocalTextSelectionColors.current`
You override this color defining a custom `TextSelectionColors`:

```
val customTextSelectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
    handleColor = Color.Transparent,
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
)

CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextSelectionColors provides customTextSelectionColors) {
   BasicTextField(
       value = text,
       onValueChange = {text = it},
       cursorBrush = SolidColor(Unspecified)
   )

   TextField(
       value = text,
       onValueChange = {text = it},
       colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(cursorColor = Color.Unspecified)
   )

}
```